# Display results from a query with PHP (Wordpress)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Trying to display results from an sql query in PHP:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM wp_celebcount
ORDER BY count DESC
```

I'm trying to display two columns: `wp_celebcount.name` & `wp_celebcount.count`

Having trouble getting the result to show with PHP - I want to show this result on my index.php Wordpress theme file. Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using Wordpress, it would be something like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT name, count FROM wp_celebcount');
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo 'Name: '.$row->name.', Count: '.$row->count.'<br/>';
}
```

It's recommended to use the `$wpdb` global as it takes care of all the database setup for you.

More information on `$wpdb` can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/).

Comment: For this to work, the table would need to be in the same database with the other WordPress tables.

Comment: Correct. But considering that the table name is 'wp_celebcount', I'm going to bet that it is :P

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you've done something like
$resultSet = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM wp_celebcount ORDER BY count DESC');

You should be able to pull out the results with

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSet))
{
   var_dump($row);
   //print an element named 'name' with echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Interesting.. Results are printing like this:


array(2) { ["Name"]=>  string(11) "Tiger Woods" ["Count"]=>  string(3) "124" } array(2) { ["Name"]=>  string(3) "Eve" ["Count"]=>  string(2) "54" } array(2) { ["Name"]=>  string(7) "Rihanna" ["Count"]=>  string(2) "46" }......

Comment: That's the output of var_dump(). You could try 
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $row );
echo '</pre>';
That should make it more readable.

Comment: OK..!  This is better. Thanks. Here's the page.. http://www.celebrything.com/

I'm trying to print the results to just show the values of names,counts without the labels..  Any ideas?